# Создание двух потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi

Нужно создать два потока, один из них позволяет ввести данные в файл А, а второй считывает информацию из файла В и записывает в файл А

Строку не записывает в файл, а также считанную строку не записывает как это исправить?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <io.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


HANDLE hMutex;
DWORD __stdcall Thread(void*)
{

    while (TRUE)
    {

        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        std::ofstream out;         
        out.open("D:\\A.txt"); 
        std:: string a;
        cout << "Enter string - ";
        cin >> a ;
        if (out.is_open())
        {

            out << a << std::endl;
        }
        out.close();
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    while (TRUE)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        std::string line;
        std::ofstream out;
        out.open("D:\\A.txt");
        std::ifstream in("D:\\B.txt"); 
        if (in.is_open())
        {
            while (getline(in, line))
            {
                if (out.is_open())
                {
                    out << line << std::endl;
                }
                out.close();
            }
        }

        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы используете Windows API, ваша функция должна соответствовать его требованиям. Ваша `Thread` должна быть объявлена вот так:

```
DWORD __stdcall Thread(void*)
```

А почему вам не использовать стандартные `async` или `thread`?